# Issue with node_modules : Can't resolve 'fs' in node_modules/xlsx

Tags: reactjs

I have a task to export data to excel and wanted to use react-export-excel library.
Unfortunately it throws me 2 errors like below.
[image]
When I tried to google it, it was recommended to update webpack.config.js and add this code

```
node: {fs: 'empty'},
externals: [
    {'./cptable': 'var cptable'},
    {'./jszip': 'jszip'}
 ]
```

The problem is that I don't have such file in my repository. How shall I then solve the problem ?
Or You have other suggestions how to overcome it ?